# Incorrect json in cross domain resquest

Tags: javascript, json, rest

here is my code

```
$.getJSON('http://../id=1397391950253&callback=?', null, function (results) {
            alert('Cross domain JS call achieved');
});
```

and result is -

```
{
    "data": [{
        "shiftY": 0,
        "regType": "FAS",
        "fuelVolume": 2373,
        "eventDate": 166625019,
        "gsmOn": true,
        "bigIconHeight": 21,
        "speed": 17,
        "roamingOn": false,
        "direction": 134,            
        "latitude": 54.8658849,
        "bigShiftY": 0,
        "iconHeight": 28,
        "useDiscreteOutput": false
    }],
    "reportDescriptor": {
        "reportTypeID": 2,
        "objectTypes": ",FAS,FTC",
        "dependencyType": "vehicle"
    }
}
```

but chrome show me this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : rtmap:1"
What is wrong in the result?

Comment: @SLaks, how to workaround this, i have to make request to external resource?

Comment: If the external resource doesn't give you a way to access it (JSONP or CORS), you can't do that.  (Unless you make a server-side proxy)

Answer (score 0):

Cross domain request can be done by two ways `JSONP` or `CORS`.

I hope, you uses `JSONP` which means return result should be the parameter of  the function named `callback` (The function name can be changed by changing the query parameter `callback` in the request eg: `&callback=myCustomCallback`). Your response from the server should be look like

```
callback({
    "data": [{
        "shiftY": 0,
        "regType": "FAS",
        "fuelVolume": 2373,
        "eventDate": 166625019,
        "gsmOn": true,
        "bigIconHeight": 21,
        "speed": 17,
        "roamingOn": false,
        "direction": 134,            
        "latitude": 54.8658849,
        "bigShiftY": 0,
        "iconHeight": 28,
        "useDiscreteOutput": false
    }],
    "reportDescriptor": {
        "reportTypeID": 2,
        "objectTypes": ",FAS,FTC",
        "dependencyType": "vehicle"
    }
})
```

Comment: unfortunately that server does not respond with JSONP specification :(